# Best approach to develop WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to create a WPF application and would like some advice on the most appropriate approach.

I want to create an RSS reader that automatically refreshes when a new RSS entry is added. The problem is that I don't want to use traditional controls (listbox/listview) to display the data. I'd like the feed items to appear in panels randomly on the screen. These panels consist of several textblocks. Each panel displays one feed item.

It would look something like this: 
[Concept](http://img810.imageshack.us/img810/7055/concepta.png)

This raises several questions:

**1: Generate panels completely from code, or use a Custom Control?**

I would model a class like a panel as described above. This class manually adds all controls to the form and drops the panel at a random location on the form. When a new RSS entry is added, an instance of this class gets instantiated and passes the rss information as parameters.

On the other hand, it might be better to create an `UserControl` for this. Is it easy to create this UserControl by code and pass it the parameters in the constructor?

**2: Can my data/panel automatically update when a new RSS entry has been added online?**

Right now I would refresh everything each (x) seconds and check against a collection of panels if there has to be created a new one. If so, create a new panel and drop it randomly on the form.

Is there a better way of doing this? I can use a local `ObservableCollection` with databinding that automatically updates a control (listbox, etc) when the collection changes, can this also be done with an online source like an RSS feed?

The most ideal way would be that my application gets notified when a new RSS entry has been added, downloads the last entry and creates a new Panel (trough code or trough a UserControl)

If this is hard thing to accomplish, I'll use the traditional refresh method.

**3: Do I have to use DependencyObject/DependencyProperty?**

I know `DependencyObject` & `DependencyProperty` expose some powerful functionality for `UserControls`, but I don't really know how to use them. Are they necessary for this kind of application?

**4: Do I have to use WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)?**

---

I'm not really experienced with "advanced" WPF stuff like advanced databindings, DependencyObjects and UserControls, but I love to learn!

Comment: You don't have to use WCF, any class that'll handle HTTP traffic will do.  You might also consider creating your own panel class that randomly positions it's children.  That way all you have to worry about is adding children to it (or binding it to an observable collection) and the rest would more or less happen automatically.

Comment: Beautiful question, but not a good SO question. Please take the time to read the [faq] so that you'll be able to write great questions that get answered instead of being closed.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend firstly looking into using the MVVM design pattern, and using an MVVM framework. Secondly, you could achieve this effect using an ItemsControl and use a Canvas as it's ItemsPanel type, then you could use a custom ItemTemplate which renders each data object using a UserControl.

The user control would have a dependency property which is the data item, and you would bind this in the item template declaration.

You could have a model which models each RSS entry (RSSEntry) and perhaps an RSSEntryViewModel which adds the x and y coordinates on the canvas.

Your screen view model would then have an ObservableCollection of RSSViewModel which you would add/delete etc to and the UI would automatically update.

You wouldn't need a service layer if you didnt want to, but as long as your view model retrieves the entries via an abstraction, it should be easy to refactor in the future.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Generate panels completely from code, or use a Custom Control?** I usually try to do as much as I can in XAML declaratively, separating logic and presentation usually helps scalability of the application and code quality - but of course there are limits. `UserControl`s generally are not supposed to have parameters in their constructors (not that they can't have them, but you have to have a parameterless constructor so the class can be instantiated from XAML).
2. **Can my data/panel automatically update when a new RSS entry has been added online?** There has to be something to send update notifications to the WPF layer, so it can update the display. In case of a RSS application, I guess you will have to manually periodically scan the RSS channels for updates (RSS is a [pull technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology)) and in case of update add the item into the `ObservableCollection` which will send the appropriate update notification for you.
3. **Do I have to use DependencyObject/DependencyProperty?** No, you can use [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). DependencyProperties are generally used in properties which will serve as binding target (the property that is declaring the binding) or in properties that will take advantage of any other DP feature - value inheritance or animation. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is enough for the properties that are bound to (that are named in the binding expression). Note that you can use [NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver) to generate the notifications for `INotifyPropertyChanged` automatically - you just create the OnPropetyChanged method and the weaver will then call it whenever any property of the object is changed! And it even integrates beautifully with Visual Studio.
4. **Do I have to use WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)?** For WCF you have to have something to communicate with - it is a communication framework after all. Do you?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use a WPF listview (or similar; not sure which control exactly), and **theme it** to match your desired "panel" idea. That is one of the great strengths of WPF. Then you get all the benefits of the built-in control, with any look you want.
2. Bind to the `ObservableCollection`; how you update that observable collection is your business. I don't think RSS has a "push notifications" part of its spec, so polling is how these things are usually done. But in the end it doesn't really matter; that part of your code is completely separate from WPF, so as long as it updates the `ObservableCollection`, you're good.
3. Either `DependencyObject`/`DependencyProperty` or `INotifyPropertyChanged` are generally necessary for any kind of WPF application with databinding. It's worth learning them, and then maybe learning a framework that abstracts them away for you.
4. No; WCF has nothing to do with WPF. You can use any technology to talk to the server that you like.

Answer (score 0):

> **1: Generate panels completely from code, or use a Custom Control?**

Create two view model classes.  One class will model the view of all your items, and one representing the content of a single item.  The former will contain an observable collection of the latter.

Build a user control to display each.

The container view will be an `ItemsControl` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to its collection of item view models, whose `ItemsPanel` is a `Canvas`, and whose `ItemContainerStyle` binds `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` properties to `Top` and `Left` properties in the item view models.  When a new item is added to the view model's collection, binding will automatically create a new panel for it.

The item view models will generate the random values of `Top` and `Left` themselves.  (You could also have them request the values from the container when they're constructed.)

(If the term "view model" doesn't mean anything to you, you need to research the model/view/view model pattern, aka MVVM.)

> **2: Can my data/panel automatically update when a new RSS entry has been added online?**

First off, you need to research how RSS aggregators work, since you're writing one.  That will explain to you the mechanics of getting updates from RSS feeds.  That problem is completely distinct from the problem of presenting the updates once you get them.

Your RSS aggregation layer will check feeds, look for new items, and when it finds new items, raise an event.  Your UI layer will handle events raised by the aggregation layer and create new view model objects for every new item received.

This use of events completely decouples the two components from each other.  For instance, you can test your UI by building a mock aggregator that generates test messages and having your UI listen to it instead of your real aggregator.  Similarly, you can test your aggregator without building the - you can just build a listener that registers for its events and dumps items to the console.

> **3: Do I have to use DependencyObject/DependencyProperty?**

You probably won't don't have to implement your own, no.

> **4: Do I have to use WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)?**

Why wouldn't you?